# JQuery AJAX div reload increases size of my div after every refresh interval

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm doing a project on laravel+voyager and in one page i want to reload data from database without refreshing the page manually so I used jQuery/AJAX, the reload works but on each reload interval it changes the size of my div and move the nav and sidebar that's outside of the div that I'm refreshing. Can anyone help?

I thought it was maybe because of jQuery version but I've tried with multiple versions and still the same result.

Page(blade.php):

```
@extends('voyager::master')
@section('page_title', 'ACD Status')
@section('page_header')
<h1 class="page-title">
    <i class="voyager-phone"></i>
    ACD Status
</h1>
@stop
@section('content')
<div class="page-content edit-add container-fluid" id=>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-bordered">
                <div id="tables">
                    <div id="reload">
                        --Data Here--
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    var timeout = setTimeout(reloadStatus, 5000);
                    var i=0;
                    function reloadStatus(){
                        $('#tables').load('/admin/acd-status #reload',function(){
                            $(this).unwrap();
                            timeout = setTimeout(reloadStatus, 5000);
                        });
                        console.log(i++);
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Any help is appreciated.
Images:
[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: what are you trying to load? what coming back from '/admin/acd-status #reload' ? can you add the html returned to this post?

Comment: /admin/acd-status is a route that returns this page

Comment: Every time you `unwrap()` it you move it up the dom tree by removing it's parent. That doesn't make sense

Comment: That's it, I just remove unwrap and voila. Thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Removed $this.unwrap()

```
@extends('voyager::master')
@section('page_title', 'ACD Status')
@section('page_header')
<h1 class="page-title">
    <i class="voyager-phone"></i>
    ACD Status
</h1>
@stop
@section('content')
<div class="page-content edit-add container-fluid" id=>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-bordered">
                <div id="tables">
                    <div id="reload">
                        --Data Here--
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    var timeout = setTimeout(reloadStatus, 5000);
                    var i=0;
                    function reloadStatus(){
                        $('#tables').load('/admin/acd-status #reload',function(){
                            timeout = setTimeout(reloadStatus, 5000);
                        });
                        console.log(i++);
                    }
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```